# How do I load Koa context into my Winston logger middleware?

Tags: middleware, koa, winston, koa2

I have a `koa` server and my frontend has been passing in some user-related data via `koa`'s context. In my `koa` app, I can get the context by doing the following:

```
// app.ts

import { Context } from "koa";

this.app.use(async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<any>) => {
    // Here I can read what's in ctx
});
```

However, I am using `apolloServer`'s `applyMiddleware` (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#apolloserverapplymiddleware) to load up my Winston logger instance.

My Winston logger instance looks something like this:

```
Winston.createLogger({
    format: Winston.format.combine(
      Winston.format.timestamp(),
      // I want to get the data from ctx to insert into here
    )......
})
```

I want to either get the data I want to be passed to the middleware via `app.ts` or directly read from `ctx` from the middleware. What is my best approach?

Comment: Could you please share code snippet of how you load Winston logger instance using `applyMiddleware` from `apolloServer`?

Comment: Hi @igor.codes, here's what I did:

`export const applyMiddlewares = (server: Server): void => {
 const middlewares: Middleware[] = [
  cors(), 
  YourMiddleware
 ];

 middlewares.forEach((middleware) => server.app.use(middleware));
};`